# How can I create a RegEx that finds a comma in a number only, and not in a string?

Tags: ios, swift, regex

**Note: I'm using Swift 5 (iOS) to try and do this.**

Let's say I have the following string:

```
This item, known as x, can be found in 1:1,234 boxes. There are 10,000, and not less, produced.
```

I'd like a RegEx that detects the comma in `1,234` and `10,000`, but ignores the other commas. I have this RegEx to find the full number with a comma, but I'm looking to just show the comma by itself.

```
([^\d]|^)\d{1,2},\d{3}([^\d]|$)
```

I'm terrible with RegEx. Can anyone give me some pointers on how to do this?

Ultimately it looks like the RegEx will need to detect 3 numbers in front, a comma, and then 1+ numbers behind.

Comment: If Lookarounds are supported, you may use `(?<=\d),(?=\d{3}(?:,\d{3})*(?!\d))`. What programming language (or regex flavor) are you using?

Comment: Using Swift 5 (iOS)

Comment: Could you do something as simple as `/(\d{1,3},\d{3})+/`?  Example: https://regex101.com/r/kt6Fo8/1

Comment: You could then use matching groups to detect the specifically the comma.

Comment: That might work for my needs @c1moore. It's at least on the right track, thank you!

Comment: What the point of detecting the comma but not the whole number ? You can just match the whole number and use matching groups to see if there is a comma

Comment: @41686d6564 - Perfect answer, thank you. I'll see if it works fine in Swift.

Comment: @aret I want to remove the specific commas in the project I'm working on.

Comment: Here's one a little more robust: https://regex101.com/r/u1HlDt/1

Answer (score 0):

Per the comment by user @41686d6564 in the comments (thank you!), here is how I accomplished what I needed to do with Swift 5:

```
desc = desc.replacingOccurrences(of: #"(?<=\d),(?=\d{3}(?:,\d{3})*(?!\d))"#, 
                                 with: "", 
                                 options: .regularExpression, 
                                 range: nil)
```